# How can “a implies not a” be true?

Tags: propositional-logic

Why does the capacity of the formula `a -> ~a` to be true seem so counterintuitive?

Can you give me some ordinary language examples of this case?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152308/discussion-on-question-by---counterintuitive-case-of-implication); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: In what context are you asking us about (A → ¬A)? Are you using a truth table definition, a english dictionary definition? Intuitionist logic, Classical Logic, Common Sense, Propositional Calculus, Aristotelian Syllogism? etc... Please provide more context.

Answer (score 4):

It might help to understand the conditional hypothetically. "If I accepted the supposition that A is true, it would follow that A is actually false. Since it is also the case that if A is false then A is false, I may conclude that A is false either way." It does indeed sound rather odd, but it is a form of reasoning by *reductio*.

An example might be the classic proof that the square root of two is irrational. You start with the supposition that there exists a pair of natural numbers n, m with no common divisor (other than 1) such that n/m equals the square root of two and then show that this supposition entails its own falsehood because n and m must both be divisible by two.

It is worth bearing in mind that the status of the sentence A → ¬A depends on the conditional you are using and on the underlying logic.

1. In the case of the material conditional from classical logic, A → ¬A is a logically contingent sentence with the same truth value as ¬A. Both (A → ¬A) → ¬A and (¬A → A) → A are theorems of classical logic. The material conditional is simply a truth function and A → ¬A can be understood as: were A true, ¬A would also be true, and since this is contradictory, A is false.
2. In intuitionistic logic and minimal logic, (A → ¬A) → ¬A is a theorem, but not (¬A → A) → A. We can understand the conditional to mean something like: I can manipulate a proof of A into a proof of ¬A and this proves ¬A. But if I manipulate a proof of ¬A into a proof of A, this only proves ¬¬A rather than A.
3. In the basic relevance logic B, (A → ¬A) → ¬A does not hold, but it is a feature of the stronger systems R and E. As with classical logic, this represents a form of reasoning by *reductio*.
4. With strict implication within normal modal logics, □(A → ¬A) holds if and only if □¬A. The strict conditional □(A → ¬A) means that A → ¬A holds in all possible worlds.
5. With Stalnaker's C2 conditional, A → ¬A is false. In Stalnaker's semantics, the consequent holds in the world as it would be if the antecedent were true. In the closest possible world in which A holds, ¬A cannot also hold, so the conditional is false. The only exception is when A is necessarily false, in which case the conditional is taken to be vacuously true.
6. With David Lewis' VC logic, A □→ ¬A is false, unless A is necessarily false, in which case the conditional is taken to be vacuously true.
7. In connexive logic, A → ¬A is always false. Connexive logic attempts to express what is meant by a non-trivial implication relation. A proposition that is true cannot imply its own falsehood.
8. If we think of logical entailment as a kind of meta level conditional, A ⊢ ¬A never holds, provided A is logically contingent.
9. With probabilistic conditionals, P(¬A | A) = 0. (Or undefined, if P(A) = 0). The fact that P(¬A | A) = 0 can be understood as stating that not-A can never hold when A is assumed true.

Answer (score 3):

I think part of the reason why it seems so counterintuitive is the same reason a statement like "if the sky is green, then the moon is made of cheese" seems counterintuitive. Namely, that when we use this kind of construction in everyday language, it's usually for cases where

1. The antecedent *can* be true, and
2. When the antecedent is true, this "causes" the consequent to be true in some way.

Neither of these hold for the example above, and similarly they don't hold for A → ¬A, since the only case where this implication holds is when A is not true to begin with. So even if it can be true logically, our intuition tells us it's false because it doesn't match the conditions above.

Comment: "*the only case where this implication holds is when A is not true to begin with*" But the implication is just false, so there is no case where it "holds". - 2. "*this implication holds is when A is not true*" So Why don't you offer a logical reasoning to prove that the implication is true?

Comment: @Speakpigeon Judging by your other replies, you seem to reject the classical definition of implication. Which is not "bad" per se, different logical formalisms exist. But let me ask you then, if you don't accept that A → B is true when A is false, how would you interpret the sentence "If I lose this bet I will eat my shoe"? If the speaker wins the bet and doesn't eat their shoe, would you consider them to have broken their promise?

Comment: "*you seem to reject the classical definition of implication*" I don't. *I don't reject the classical definition*. The definition I reject is not "*classical*". The only classical definition we know of is that of Aristotle's. - 2. "*how would you interpret the sentence "If I lose this bet I will eat my shoe"?*" Not telling you that, but it's really easy. Standard logic. Why are you unable to see it? - 3. "*If the speaker wins the bet and doesn't eat their shoe, would you consider them to have broken their promise?*" His promise to eat his shoe? Nobody takes it as a true promise.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the capacity of the formula 'a -> ~a' to be true seem so counterintuitive?

Because such a conditional is true only in the case where the assertion of (a) is a contradiction, to make this clear, let us translate the variables into English.

(a) = it is the case that (a)

(~a) = it is not the case that (a)

With the above translation of the variables given, a common misunderstanding is assuming that (a) is actually true, which would result in a straightforward contradiction as can be demonstrated with the following syllogism:

(P1) a -> ~a

(P2) a

(P3) ~a [derived from P1 and P2]

Conclusion: a ∧ ~a

If this understanding were to be correct, that the assertion of [a -> ~a] necessitates the assertion [a ∧ ~a], then [a -> ~a] would always be false, but the mere assertion of [a -> ~a] is not the same as stating that the syllogism above is true;[a -> ~a] does not assert or entail (a), the second premise above must be introduced, it can not be deduced from [a -> ~a] alone.

But this is not the case, rather, the implication (->) symbol is a conditional symbol that makes the sentence take the English form "If (a) then (~a)", or to put it in a more fleshed-out form:

"***IF*** it is the case that (a) ***THEN*** it is not the case that (a)"

That is to say, if you assume that (a) is the case then you will find (a) not to be a case. Hence the sentence is asserting in essence that (a) is a contradiction, **not** that (a) is the case.

> Can you give me some ordinary language examples of this case?

Sure, here is a clear example. If we assume that "indescribable" is a descriptive word (which it is) then you get the following:

If [Tom is indescribable] then [Tom is describable]

(a) = it is the case that [Tom is indescribable] == [Tom is indescribable]

(~a) = it is not the case that [Tom is indescribable] == it is the case that [Tom is describable] == [Tom is describable]

Here we can see that the statement "If [Tom is indescribable] then [Tom is describable]" takes the form "a -> ~a" and is true. Note how asserting that *it is the case in reality* that Tom is indescribable, is different from asserting that "if we were to claim that Tom is indescribable, then we would be forced to conclude that he is describable"; the former is false whilst the latter is clearly true.

- Feel free to let me know if you need any further clarification

Comment: The material conditional A → B is logically equivalent to ¬A ∨ B. So A → ¬A is logically equivalent to ¬A ∨ ¬A, which is logically equivalent to ¬A. So A → ¬A is a logically contingent proposition that has the same truth value as ¬A. It does not require A to be a contradiction.

Comment: @Bumble If A → ¬A is logically equivalent to ¬A, then to assert A → ¬A is to assert ¬A *must* be the case. And to assert that ¬A *must* be the case is to assert that A being the case would be a contradiction...... I don't see where I erred

Comment: No. To assert A → ¬A is equivalent (at least in its truth conditions) to asserting ¬A. There is no must about it.

Comment: @Bumble The must is to emphasize the fact that you are continuously asserting ¬A (it's not being used in a modal sense). If we are speaking purely in terms of truth conditionals, then asserting ¬A would mean that asserting A would be a contradiction, meaning A would entail a contradiction, and would hence be the logical equivalent of a contradiction (A would entail a contradiction and the contradiction would entail A). If we are speaking in terms of the semantics of A → ¬A, then it seems obvious that the individual who asserts such is asserting that A is a contradiction....

Comment: as the individual would be claiming that for you to assert A is to assert its negation, meaning that A would be contradictory. This looks to be trivially true.

Comment: Again, no. Provided A is a contingent proposition, to assert ¬A is simply to assert that it is not the case that A. It does not follow that asserting A would be a contradiction. Asserting both A and ¬A would be a contradiction. Asserting A would simply be to assert a falsehood. If I assert, "The sun is cold," I am asserting a falsehood, not a contradiction.

Comment: @Bumble In terms of the logic, you are simply incorrect, do the truth table for yourself, ¬A <-> [A -> (A ∧ ¬A)] is a tautology; Asserting ¬A is the same as asserting that A entails a contradiction. In terms of the semantics, there is a clear semantic difference when one asserts the negation of something and when one asserts that to assert (x) is to not assert (x), the topic of discussion is the later, not the former. lol

Comment: That is not what I am saying at all. I said that ¬A is logically equivalent to A → ¬A. That is correct and the truth table confirms it. I don't know why you keep talking about assertion. The question is asking why it is possible for A → ¬A to be true.

Comment: @Bumble At this point you are needlessly dragging on this conversation. You took issue with me stating that asserting ¬A entails that A is a contradiction, I provided you with a clear tautological formulation that shows that this is the case; ¬A <-> [A -> (A ∧ ¬A)]. The question asked was "Why does the capacity of the formula 'a -> ~a' to be true seem so counterintuitive?"; I provided the OP with an answer mostly focusing on the semantic reasons *dealing with the formulation itself*, and provided him with an ordinary language example. I no longer see a matter of contention, have a nice day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152315/discussion-between-bumble-and-max-maxman).

Answer (score 0):

In classical logic, the implication `A → B` is equivalent to `¬A ∨ B`. So, when `B` is `¬A`, the implication `A → ¬A` can be represented as `¬A ∨ ¬A`, which is equivalent to `¬A`. This statement holds true when `A` is false, as `¬False = True`.

Understanding that this reduces to `¬A`, an ordinary language example would be the claim *"it is false that the sun doesn't exist"*, which is true because the internal claim *"the sun doesn't exist"* is false (purportedly, assuming we are not brains in vats, etc.)

Comment: "*In classical logic, the implication A → B is equivalent to ¬A ∨ B*" Classical logic is Aristotelian logic and nothing else, so, no,  the implication A → B is not equivalent to ¬A ∨ B. - 2. "*because the internal claim "the sun doesn't exist" is false*" You don't prove an implication true by assuming a particular case. The implication we are discussing is A → ¬A. If you assume ¬A, the implication is no longer A → ¬A, it is ¬A → (A → ¬A).

Comment: @Speakpigeon See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional, also see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/630399

Comment: See the scholarship on Aristotle's texts.

Answer (score -2):

The only time a -> ~a is when a is false. When a is false, a can imply anything. This is known as the principle of explosion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion

(Latin: ex falso [sequitur] quodlibet, 'from falsehood, anything [follows]'; or ex contradictione [sequitur] quodlibet, 'from contradiction, anything [follows]')

As conifold pointed out, this can come up in an argument from contradiction.

edit. My answer seems... controversial, but there's another answer on this stackexchange making the same connection that seems more well-received - perhaps it's explained better there: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/10528/49717

And here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212338/why-if-the-antecedent-p-is-false-and-the-consequence-q-true-then-the-implicati

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152318/discussion-on-answer-by-tkol-counterintuitive-case-of-implication); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -2):

The idea that the implication A → ¬A could be true in some cases is a theoretic construct. And, sometimes, theoretic constructs are just false. That is, they do not match up with the real world. They are only theoretic constructs.

It helps sometimes in order to see through these theoretic constructs to focus on reality by looking at an actual example.

Let us suppose, then, that A stands for the statement “God exists”.

There are only two cases to consider:

> (1) God exists
>
> (2) God doesn't exist

That is, cases A and ¬A.

First:

> A is true. If A is true, then God exists, so we can say reasonably that A implies that God exists. This is just the implication A → A. And it is obviously true.

Second:

> A is false. If A is false, God doesn't exist, and it is ¬A which is true. Thus, if ¬A is true, then God doesn't exist. That is: If ¬A, then ¬A. This just means that the implication ¬A → ¬A is true, which again is obviously true.

And there is no other case to consider. We have exhausted all logical possibilities.

In particular, we find no case where the implication A → ¬A would be true! Not in the real world, anyway.

There is nothing unintuitive about this.

NOTA: This is a "*politically correct*" rewording of **Baby_philosopher**'s answer, which has been deleted.

I tried to respect the philosophical substance.

Alleged instance of A → ¬A:

> *Let A be "**B might be false**" so Not-A is "**B is true**", I would argue that A implies that not-A is possibly true, and so it is possible that A implies not-A.*

Clearly, "**B might be false**" does not imply "**B is true**", so this example does not show that it is possible that A implies not-A.

However, this is an example of A where A does not imply not-A, which proves that it is possible that A does not imply not-A, if this is not self-evident to you.

Another alleged instance of A → ¬A:

> If Tom is indescribable then Tom is describable.

This is just good old sophistry!

Either you are equivocating on the word "indescribable", or you are contradicting yourself when you suppose that it is true that Tom is indescribable; this even before you could arrive at the conclusion that Tom is describable.

Either way, the example is just nonsense, as most people seem to realise this.

This reminds me of the idea that for us to be able to enjoy reading fiction, we have to suspend disbelief. Here, to "enjoy" the paradox, we have to suspend logical acumen.

Comment: What if *A* were “one apple is the same as two apples” or “it’s not the case that ‘if you agree with me, then you agree with me,’”?

Comment: @PW_246 "*What if A were "one apple is the same as two apples" or “it’s not the case that ‘if you agree with me, then you agree with me’”* OMG, A is false in both cases, so not-A is true, but this only implies that you are going to say "Ah-ah, gotcha!" Go on, explain  to me why ¬A → (A → ¬A) is *tau-to-lo-gi-cal*! I can't seem to get enough of that stuff! You are wasting your time, you know?

Comment: I’m ultimately trying to see what your understanding of implication is. You say, “ In particular, we find no case where the implication A→¬A would be true! Not in the real world, anyway.” So no examples of *(A→¬A)→¬A* are applicable to the real world? I’m just trying to see what your actual position is, since it seems to be either a very nuanced position, or a position that is not that well thought-out. P.S., I don’t think *¬A→(A→¬A)* is true when *P→Q* means “whenever P holds, Q also holds ” and *¬A* means “A is currently falsifiable.”

Comment: @PW_246 "*your understanding of implication*" It is like that of everyone else. Common sense. As opposed to the purely theoretic and ultimately false axiom that the implication is logically equivalent to the horseshoe. Common says that A → ¬A is false. - 2. "*a very nuanced position or . . . not that well thought-out*" It all comes down to common sense and our logical intuition. You learned some theoretic construct at school and you think the stuff is "well thought out". *Because?* Because you haven't really thought about it, so you are unable to fault the theoretic stuff.

Comment: @PW_246 "*P.S., I don’t think ¬A→(A→¬A) is true when P→Q means “whenever P holds, Q also holds ” and ¬A means “A is currently falsifiable.”*" Are you admitting that when you say that A → ¬A is true when A is false, you don't mean that the implication A → ¬A is true but that the horseshoe A ⊃ ¬A is true if A is false? Please explain to me how mathematicians are not wasting everybody's time when they call the horseshoe A ⊃ B not a horseshoe but "*the implication A → B*"? - 2. "*and ¬A means “A is currently falsifiable.*" ¬A just means "A is false". Falsifiability is something else.

Comment: I wouldn’t day they’re wasting people’s time, even though I think there is a difference between what I would call an ‘implication’ and what I would call a ‘conditional.’ Either way, what I’m saying is that if A→¬A holds, then ¬A holds. Also, I like to think of negation as weaker than mere falsity in the same way that people use the weaker inclusive or as opposed to the stronger exclusive or.

Comment: @PW_246 "*there is a difference between . . . an ‘implication’ and . . . a ‘conditional’*" The difference is that A implies means If A, then B, and vice versa. I'd love to see what *you would call* a counterexample to that! - 2. "*if A→¬A holds, then ¬A holds. *" No, . - "*I like to think of negation as weaker than mere falsity*" Sure, negating A doesn't make A false.

Comment: If we’re having a discussion right now, then if it’s the 30th of March, then we’re having a discussion right now, but that doesn’t mean that if we’re having a discussion right now, then whenever it’s March 30th, we’re having a discussion. Also, don’t you think that the horseshoe follows from implication? If so, then it must be that if A⊃¬A is true precisely when ¬A is true, then ¬A is also true whenever A→¬A is true.

Comment: I suspect most discussion here could be simply resolved if the poster defined what their use of  → is intended to mean, since it is being used in a nonstandard way ( In respect to how it is used in a typical discrete math, Philosphy 101/Logic Class) I suspsect something like the dictionary definition of implication is being used?

Comment: More specifically, in your notion of implication, when is  p → q true, and when is it false- and how does its truth value relate to the truth values of p, and q respectively, how can we know when p implies q is true or false?

Comment: The post may have in mind some kind of connexive conditional, or maybe a relevant conditional from one of the relevance logics. Such conditionals have to be nonmonotonic, since for any monotonic conditional, including the material conditional, B entails A → B for any A, B, so substituting ¬A for B gives ¬A entails A → ¬A.

Comment: @MichaelCarey "*I suspect most discussion here could be simply resolved if the poster defined what their use of → is intended to mean*" I use the arrow → to mean the implication. I make this immediately clear in my answer with the phrase "the implication A → ¬A". Apparently, this is not enough. - 2. "*since it is being used in a nonstandard way ( In respect to how it is used in a typical discrete math, Philosphy 101/Logic Class)*" My use is 100% standard. What is not standard is what mathematicians mean by "A implies B".

Comment: @Speakpigeon If you could please give a reference to the definition of "the implication" you are using or expand on it in your answer- I believe it would be helpful. I don't believe I am the only one unsure about your use of implication. I agree that Logisticians/Mathematicians "truth conditional" or Russell's "Material Implication" is a nonstandard use of "if/implication" which doesnt generally match with everyday language.

Comment: If we are using common sense reasoning, Let A be " B might be false" so Not A is " B is true", I would argue that A implies that not A is possibly true, and so it is possible that A implies not A.